# PHP Loop with While Loop confusion

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I currently have a simple `WHILE` loop running as follows:

```
while($los = $result->fetch_row())
    {
        echo"<tr><td>".$los[0]."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$los[1]."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$los[2]."</td></tr>";
    }
```

The contents of `$los` is as follows:

```
London    => 15 => 32
Glasgow   => 23 => 45
Leeds     => 1  => 12
Truro     => 5  => 23
```

All working fine but what I am struggling with is that I have a second array `$outs`, the contents of which are:

```
London    => 3 
Glasgow   => 5 
Liverpool => 2
Poole     => 1
```

Within the first `while` loop I am trying to subtract the `value` for `$outs` from `$los` when the location name matches.  I have tried adding the following  inside the while loop but no joy:

```
if($los[0] == $outs[0]){
    $los[1] = $los[1]-$outs[1];
}
```

But no joy, also when I have tried `print_r($outs)` from within the while loop, all it returns is:

```
Poole     => 1
Poole     => 1
Poole     => 1
Poole     => 1
```

I cannot fathom where I am going wrong or even if this is possible.  Is the `$outs` array being modified as it's within the first loop?  Any ideas, suggestion or pointers welcomed on how I might achieve this.

**VAR DUMPS**

So, as requested the contents of the two arrays are:

*$los*

```
London    => 15 => 32
Glasgow   => 23 => 45
Leeds     => 1  => 12
Truro     => 5  => 23
```

*$outs*

```
London    => 3 
Glasgow   => 5 
Liverpool => 2
Poole     => 1
```

However, when I vardump or print_r for `$outs` when it is in the `while($los = $result->fetch_row())` the contents are:

```
Poole     => 1
Poole     => 1
Poole     => 1
Poole     => 1
```

**FURTHER CODE**

The code to obtain the array for `$outs` is:

```
$query19 = "SELECT Country, COUNT(Country), Resp FROM `tresults_` WHERE q39 = 'Complete' GROUP BY Country;";

$result19 = $mysqli->query($query19);

while($row19 = $result19->fetch_assoc()){
    $outs = $row19;
}
```

Comment: `London => 15 => 32` what are you trying to denote with this notation? Have you tried fetching as an associative array and foreach-ing instead?

Comment: Show us your full php code. We are unable to help you if your Question has insufficient code.

Comment: This should be while($row19 = $result19->fetch_assoc()){
    $outs[] = $row19;
} you are replacing $outs variable, please make it an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider to post the RAW Content that was produced by var_dump and include a full but minimal script to produce the error.

What is unclear here seem to be if `$outs` is a (1) Key-Value Array or a if it's (2) containing sub-arrays.

**Option 1:**

```
$outs = [
    "London"    => 3,
    "Glasgow"   => 5,
    "Liverpool" => 2,
    "Poole"     => 1
];
```

**Option 2:**

```
$outs = [
    ["London", 3],
    ["Glasgow", 5],
    ["Liverpool", 2],
    ["Poole", 1]
];
```

I did for testing assume your input rows look like this:

```
$citys = [
    ["London", 15, 32],
    ["Glasgow", 23, 45],
    ["Leeds", 1, 12],
    ["Truro", 5, 23]
];
```

Depending on this you sould adjust the `if` inside your while loop.

For *option 1*:

```
foreach ($citys as $los) {
    if (array_key_exists($los[0], $outs)) {
        $los[1] = $los[1] - $outs[$los[0]];
    }

    echo " <tr><td > " . $los[0] . "</td > ";
    echo "<td > " . $los[1] . "</td > ";
    echo "<td > " . $los[2] . "</td ></tr > ";
}
```

For *option 2* it's a little bit more code, as we need to search for the cityname index inside `$outs` first. In php > 5.5 it could be done using `array_column` which would be easier.

```
foreach ($citys as $los) {
    $indexInOuts = null;
    foreach($outs as $index => $out){
        if($los[0] === $out[0]){
            $indexInOuts = $index;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($indexInOuts !== null){
        $los[1] = $los[1] - $outs[$indexInOuts][1];
    }

    echo " <tr><td > " . $los[0] . "</td > ";
    echo "<td > " . $los[1] . "</td > ";
    echo "<td > " . $los[2] . "</td ></tr > ";
}
```

The output for both options would be like:

```
London 12 32 
Glasgow 18 45 
Leeds 1 12 
Truro 5 23
```

And as stated in the comments you are replacing the $outs every time. So edit it to look like this:

```
$outs = [];
while ($row19 = $result19->fetch_assoc()) {
   $outs[] = $row19;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback.  I'm going to have a look at both options and will let you know.  Also appreciate the feedback re. `Please consider to post the RAW Content that was produced by var_dump and include a full but minimal script to produce the error.`